# list all implements interface through coding

Tags: java, interface

Is it possible to list all the implemented interface by any class.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Why wouldn't you look at the class? What's the usecase?

Comment: Have you at least searched for an answer before asking here?

Comment: @coder005 At-least accept one answer, otherwise elaborate, what you want ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (myObject instanceof InterfaceName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Reflection**, you can achieve this, use the below code, it will list all the implemented interface by your class `MyClass`, and import the `java.lang.reflect.Type` package in your java file.

```
    MyClass s = new MyClass();
    Type[] ifaces = s.getClass().getInterfaces();
    for(int i=0;i<ifaces.length;i++)
    System.out.print (ifaces[i]);
```